# Java Generics and Collection Reading references

Tags: java, generics, collections

Though i know some working knowledge Generics and Collections and can also say that have some hands on experience about using Collection API.

But when it comes to some Good knowledge about generics i must say i always rely on Google to find my answers.

I am looking for some references to get some in-depth idea about Generics and Collections any online reference material or Book suggestion is most welcome.

I am not sure how constructive this question is, so i am fine if this question get closed in few minutes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This (Angelika Langer's FAQ)](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is the best place to learn everything you need to know about java generics.

Comment: thanks!! looking good, will surely go through it.

Comment: +1; totally agree. I *still* refer to it, after all these years.

Answer (score 3):

[Angelika's generics page](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html) is still one of the best references I know; I still refer to it when I forget something (or just don't know).

Answer (score 1):

Entire collection framework by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework)

Oracle documentation about [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).

Learn [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This book is also good

[http://www.amazon.com/Java-Generics-Collections-Maurice-Naftalin/dp/0596527756](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527756)